# How do I parse array of objects and compare it with other array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I have an array of objects that I would like to know how to parse, find the keys that are in my other array and check if they are null in the initial array of objects.

How can I achieve this?

So I have something like:

```
[{"nonmandatoryfield":"","mandatoryfield1":"1","mandatoryfield2":"2",
  "mandatoryfield3":"3"}]
```

now I would like to check if keys: [mandatoryfield1, mandatoryfield2, mandatoryfield3] values are null

In JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
const mandatoryFieldNames = [
  'mandatoryfield1',
  'mandatoryfield2',
  'mandatoryfield3',
];

const data = [
  {
    nonmandatoryfield: '',
    mandatoryfield1: '1',
    mandatoryfield2: '2',
    mandatoryfield3: '3',
  },
  {
    nonmandatoryfield: '',
    mandatoryfield1: null,
    mandatoryfield2: '2',
    mandatoryfield3: '3',
  },
];

const dataWithMandatoryFields = data.filter(item =>
  mandatoryFieldNames.every(field => item[field]),
);
```